# What's the purpose of multisample renderbuffers

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

If I understand it correctly, renderbuffers can only be used as attachments for a framebuffer, and can't be read or reused in any way. If that is so, what is the use case for multisampled renderbuffer, if they have no effect what data is written to other FBO attachments? Or is it somehow possible to use them to get hardware MSAA outside of the main backbuffer (WebGL2 doesn't support multisampled textures yet)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You render to a multisample renderbuffer. You then call [`gl.blitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) to *resolve* it into a normal texture or the backbuffer. In this way you get multi-sampled anti aliasing (MSAA)

This is how the browser itself gives you an antialiased canvas. In WebGL2 you can make multisampled renderbuffers yourself. In WebGL1 you could not.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Do you know how it compares performance-wise to native OpenGL multisampled textures, or to rendering to a larger texture and then downscaling it?

Comment: Or am I missing the point of native MS textures, and they can only be used to manually select samples and `blitFramebuffer` is still required to use them as normal textures?

Comment: AFAIK multisampled textures have the advantage that they actually are textures that are 2x 4x 16x in size. So, when you render to them you get the speed benefits of the MSAA algorithm but when you sample them as a normal texture you get access to the full resolution. Something you can't do with multisampled renderbuffers.  Perf wise they're the same if you use them the same way (just render and blit). Since you can't use an ms renderbuffer as a source though you'd have to call blit to copy it to a texture if you wanted to do that and that would be a big perf diff.

Comment: I looked it up and it seems that the only reason to use MS textures is if you want to implement your own resolve by binding them to `sampler2DMS` and passing sample ID as the extra argument to texture functions. That seems really niche, i.e. maybe someone wants to use it for PCF shadows or something.

Otherwise, they have to be blitted to another buffer anyway so there seems to be no reason to use them over renderbuffers. This is what I wanted anyway, I just missed the use of the blit function. Thanks, got my stuff working now :)